# Need help to do 2d drafting

Tags: c#, vb.net, drawing, autocad

I have all the data of a door in the form of system.drawing.rectangle which comes from my own tool.
I have tried to build a 2d drafting (technical sheet) with all the dimensions, but it do not seems professional enough to send to a customer.

[Here is my attempt](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D6613292_1094279_1900566).

Is there a library, free or not, which I could use to make this?
I think I can export to AutoCAD and then use the built in tool, have someone try this?

I work with csharp/vb.net.

Edit: More precisions

I have two tools. Actually they are two projects from the same solution on Visual Studio.

The first one is to configure the door, select model, change glasses, dimensions, etc.
After it is configured I have all the data in objects which are basically rectangles.

The second one is to make the 2d drafting, which I make without respecting any [standards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_drawing).

I’m not sure if I can link images from Google here but if you search “engineering drawing” you will find many.

The goal is to send the spec to the customer for verification.

So I have two choices:

1. Improve my second tool by implementing some standards, we only make
   doors after all.
2. Do some mapping to third party tools.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit? you did that drawing with `System.Drawing`, right? now, what's wrong about it? what would you expect to achieve?

Comment: Sure, i edited my principal post.

Comment: You are trying to build a professionally looking drawing with GDI+? Good luck with that.

Comment: @RiverSoul I still don't understand... all that can be easily achieved with CAD applications such as AutoCAD.. why would you implement your own?

Comment: I totally agree for the second tool. But the first one has a lot of stuff in it and it was designed user-friendly and foolproof, seriously a kid could use it. On top of that a complete order can be complete within a minute. That’s why we do not use CAD tools in this context.

Comment: @Riversoul then you answered your own question. Still, if you need to implement graphics-intensive functionality, winforms is not your friend. WPF is, it has much greater capabilities when it comes to graphics, and is also vector-based, and hardware accelerated. That is the framework that will allow you to code professional stuff, not winforms, which in this point is actually a dinosaur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way to do what you're trying to do is to write your UI and algorithms as a plugin for the CAD engine, then use your code to generate the CAD drawing using the native CAD API. AutoCAD is probably overkill for your needs, but [Bricscad](http://www.bricsys.com/bricscad/) is fairly inexpensive and can do what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll look at these suggestions.